# My data inserts but data table wont reload (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using an ajax code that inserts data into the database using modal however, the `ajax.reload` doesn't work because of some problems. I used the console and network tab of the chrome to see what is the error. It seems that the value for my ajax data is NULL. I Hope someone can help me.

[Screenshots of the error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC6DM.png)

[Screenshot from network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azkmq.png)

[Screenshot of null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ZJZ.png)

## Ajax code and Controller function

```js
 $('#newConsigneeSubmit').on("click", function(){

var supp_code      = $("input[name=supp_code]").val();
var address1       = $("input[name=address1]").val();
var address2             = $("input[name=address2]").val(); 
var country          = $("input[name=country] ").val();
var description        = $("input[name=description]").val();
var tel_num        = $("input[name=tel_num]").val();
var fax_num         = $("input[name=fax_num]").val();
var contact_person           = $("input[name=contact_person]").val();
var email         = $("input[name=email]").val();
var consol_agent         = $("input[name=consol_agent]").val();
var disc1         = $("input[name=disc1]").val();
var disc2         = $("input[name=disc2]").val();
var disc3         = $("input[name=disc3]").val();
var disc4         = $("input[name=disc4]").val();
var disc5         = $("input[name=disc5]").val();
var last_transaction         = $("input[name=last_transaction]").val();
var old_supplier         = $("input[name=old_supplier]").val();

var sfm_table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable(); 



  $.ajax({
    
    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>SFM/insert',
    type:'post',
    
    data:{ 
      'supp_code' : supp_code , 'address1' : address1 , 'address2' : address2 ,'country' : country , 
      'description' : description ,'tel_num' : tel_num , 'fax_num' : fax_num ,'contact_person' : contact_person ,
       'email' : email , 'consol_agent' : consol_agent , 'disc1' : disc1 ,'disc2' : disc2 
       , 'disc3' : disc3 ,'disc4' : disc4 , 'disc5' : disc5 ,'last_transaction' : last_transaction  ,'old_supplier' : old_supplier
         },

      
      success: function(data) {
       
        
                        if(data) {

                         sfm_table.ajax.reload()
                        
                          $("#sfm_modal").modal('hide');
                         
                           swal("Data Inserted", {
                                icon: "success"
                            });

                            
                       
                        } else {
                          
                         
                           swal("Error", {
                                icon: "error"
                            });

     
                        
                    }
        
      }
    });
   
                            
  });
```

```html
 function insert()
 {
     $data1 = array(
  'SUPP_CODE'=> $this->input->post('supp_code'),
  'ADDRESS'=> $this->input->post('address1'),
  'ADDRESS2'=> $this->input->post('address2'),
  'COUNTRY'=> $this->input->post('country'),
  'DESCRIPTION'=> $this->input->post('description'),
  'TEL_NO'=> $this->input->post('tel_num'),
  'FAX_NO'=> $this->input->post('fax_num'),
  'CONTACT'=> $this->input->post('contact_person'),
  'EMAIL'=> $this->input->post('email'),
  'CONS_AGENT'=> $this->input->post('consol_agent'),
  'DISC1'=> $this->input->post('disc1'),
  'DISC2'=> $this->input->post('disc2'),
  'DISC3'=> $this->input->post('disc3'),
  'DISC4'=> $this->input->post('disc4'),
  'DISC5'=> $this->input->post('disc5'),
  'LAST_TRANS'=> $this->input->post('last_transaction'),
  'SUPP_CODE2'=> $this->input->post('old_supplier')
       );

   $insertReturn = $this->system_model->insert('fo_supp', $data1);
  
   echo json_encode($insertReturn);

 }
```

## SFM_VIEW

```html
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="x_panel">
            <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Supplier Master File

                    <small></small>
                </h2>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li>
                        <a class="collapse-link">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
       <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
      </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Settings 1
                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Settings 2
                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="x_content">
                <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sfm_modal" style="float: right;">
     <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
     <span>Add New Data</span>
    
   </button>
                </div>
                <table id="datatable-buttons" name="sfm_table"  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Supplier Code
                            </th>
                            <th>Address
                            </th>
                            <th>Country
                            </th>
                            <th>Description
                            </th>
                            <th>Telephone Number
                            </th>
                            <th>Fax Number
                            </th>
                            <th>Contact Person
                            </th>
                            <th>Email
                            </th>

                            <th>Actions
                            </th>
                            <th>Consolidating Agent
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 1
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 2
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 3
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 4
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 5
                            </th>
                            <th>Last Transaction
                            </th>
                            <th>Old Supplier
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php if(!empty($fo_supp)): ?>
                        <?php foreach($fo_supp as $supp): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->ADDRESS." ".$supp->ADDRESS2?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->COUNTRY?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DESCRIPTION?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->TEL_NO?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->FAX_NO?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->CONTACT?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->EMAIL?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
            
                                <a href="#sfm_modal_edit"  data-target="#sfm_modal_edit" id='<?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>' class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i>
         </a>

        
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i>
         </a>
                            </td>
      
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->CONS_AGENT?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC1?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC2?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC3?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC4?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC5?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=  $supp->LAST_TRANS ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE2?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                            <td>
                                <span class="text-danger"> Not Available </span>
                            </td>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--MODAL HERE-->
        <div class="modal fade" name="sfm_modal " id="sfm_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Create New Supplier
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                <!-- left column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Supplier Code</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Supplier Code</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="supp_code" id="supp_code" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '999999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Address</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Address 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address2" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address2" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Country</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Country</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control col-md-10" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="form-group"><label for="new_zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style = "visibility: hidden;">Description</label><span class="label label-default" >Supplier Code</span><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-sm-7"><label for="new_zip_detail" class="sr-only" style = "visibility: hidden;">City, State Country</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip_detail" placeholder="City, State Country" disabled=""></div></div> -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Description</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Description</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Telephone Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Telephone Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_num" id="tel_num" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Fax Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Fax Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fax_num" id="fax_num" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Consolidating Agent</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Consolidating Agent</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="consol_agent" class="form-control" id="consol_agent" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                </div>
                                <!-- right column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Email</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Email</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Contact Person</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Contact Person</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_person" id="contact_person" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 1</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 1</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc1" id="disc1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc2" id="disc2" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 3</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 3</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc3" id="disc3" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 4</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 4</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc4" id="disc4" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 5</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 5</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc5" id="disc5" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Last Transaction</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Last Transaction</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_transaction" id="last_transaction" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999/99/99'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Old Supplier</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Old Supplier</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="old_supplier" id="old_supplier" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End main input boxes, starting a new "row" -->
                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="newConsigneeReset">Reset</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="newConsigneeSubmit">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Modal Footer -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- End modal body div -->
            </div>
            <!-- End modal content div -->
        </div>
        <!-- End modal dialog div -->
    </div>
    <!-- End modal div -->



</div>
<!-- END DIV -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /page content -->
```

Comment: Need to see the data (POST Body) that gets sent TO the server. Or the contents of the form elements at the time of the AJAX call.

Comment: Okay i will update my post @RandyCasburn

Comment: You need to fix database error first check which field should be null and add validation as well accordingly.

Comment: When inserting data from modal it works.. The problem is reloading the data table @Kittu

Comment: The problem is I think in my ajax code (data part) and controller I guess. @Kittu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors 01 - Close `</form>` before the `div`**

```
    </form>
</div> <--- THIS DIV
```

**remove `id` from `<button>` and use only for `<form>`**

```
# change button type
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
# use below form ID
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal">
```

**In JS**

```
#change
$('#newConsigneeSubmit').on("click", function(){
# to this
$("#form1").submit(function (e) {

#change
var supp_code      = $("input[name=supp_code]").val();
# to this
var supp_code = $('#supp_code').val();
```

---

**FYI:** Before you insert check all the data has passed to your controller. (`print_r($arrayName);die;`)

Comment: Can i ask one more question? Why does my validation if success not working anymore? It just reloads automatically.

Comment: @cjpm give me sometime will check and let you know. middle of work

Comment: Sure! Take your time sir! I appreciate it :)

Comment: @cjpm whats the issue can you explain

Comment: After I did all the solutions you provided, the reload of datatable works. However, my validation in the part of success: function(data) doesn't work anymore. I noticed it when the sweet alert did not show after a successful insert. I also noticed it when i tried to enter value that is already found in the database which an error alert should be seen

Comment: in success write `console.log(data)` and check

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It says true however the log doesn't stay in the console because it reloads.